# Can I invert the argument in this way?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is it permissible for me to invert the argument as follows:
$$f(1/z) = \frac{c}{z^n}\implies f(z) = \frac{c}{\frac{1}{z^n}}\implies f(z) = cz^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. But I feel I should point out one extra step: $$f(1/z) = \frac{c}{z^n} \implies f(z) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n}} = \frac{c}{\frac{1}{z^n}} = cz^n.$$

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @ivoterek! :-)

Comment: Hi @ivoterek, going back one step earlier: I have z^n*f(1/z) = c implies f(1/z) = c / z^n.  Is it ok to divide the z^n factor to bring it over to the r.h.s.?  There are not issues of dividing by zero, right?  Thanks,

Comment: There's no issues, because from the moment you wrote $f(1/z)$, we're excluding zero from our analysis.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much, @ivoterek :-)

Comment: But if you start with $f(z) = cz^n$, which is valid for all $z$, and from this you want to go to $f(1/z) = cz^n$, then you have to throw $0$ out. Ok?

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind, @ivoterek.  BTW, is it also ok, because the context is complex analysis?  There's a pole of f (of order n) at infinity, so then there is a pole (of order n) at zero of the function f(1/z).  Then z^nf(1/z) has no poles.  If f is entire then z^nf(1/z) = c, by Liouville's Theorem.  Here is where I divide over the z^n factor...

Comment: Oh boy, that escalated quickly. But yes, what you said is correct.

Comment: :-)  I have so many questions, @ivoterek.  one day at a time :-).  Thanks!

Comment: I asked a separate question just now re: the real variable setting.  Feel free to comment on that, if you'd like to, @IvoTerek.  Thanks and have a great night!

Comment: (I guess I am just *very* paranoid with this algebraic manipulation ...)